# Is it possible to add two ClickEvents in one word in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

Now I have the following command, but these command does not work:

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"Click here","color":"aqua","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/give @p diamond 2"},"clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/give @p diamond 2"}},{"text":" for 2","color":"none"},{"text":" diamonds","color":"blue"}},{"text":"!","color":"none"}]
```

Is it possible to place 2 commands in one "word"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have two `clickEvent` tags on the same word.  Among other things, it's not valid JSON.  So you can't do it this way.

However, you can use [`/trigger`](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#trigger) to achieve a similar effect (though you will need several command blocks).  You'd need to have several command blocks that first run the commands you want on players with a specific scoreboard value and then clear that scoreboard value.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?